# Xml file downloading throwing null exception vb.net vsto

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I am trying to download an xml file to a local drive using a web client, and it is throwing a null exception and I'm not sure why. My code is:

```
Imports System.Net

Sub downloadfile
Dim wc as New WebClient
Dim filesave As String = "D:\Data\Test\test_addresses3.xml"
Dim url As String = "http://www.simon-kucher.com/sites/default/files/test_addresses3.xml"

wc.DownloadFile(url, filesave)

End Sub
```

The message I get when I run this is:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Value cannot be null.

I think there is something wrong with the url I am using, but I can't work out what it is?

Comment: I just tried the code. It's actually working. Maybe the link was down when you tried running the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I realised that I had made an error in code further up which was causing it to skip the lines assigning the url and save locations. This code is now working fine